# Add a new contextMenu item in ace editor like 'Spellcheck'

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, ace-editor

I need to add a new contextMenu item in right-click menu list.
Anyone please tell the steps for appending the available contextMenu list and how to add some functionality on its click.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ace doesn't control the context menu.
It is controlled by the broser which doesn't provide standard and widely implemented way to customize it.
You could override the whole contextmenu like cloud9 does